# How do i access the text value of a UITextField ios swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am new to ios programming and this may be me being very stupid (quite likely).

I have two viewcontrollers in my app. To view the second viewcontroller i use a seque and then return to the first viewcontroller with the back button on the seconf viewcontroller navigation bar. This all works fine.

On the second viewcontroller i have a UITextField which is populated following a background notification event with text returned from an external class.

The first time i seque to the second viewcontroller and trigger the event to populate the UITextField it works correctly.

If i then go back to the first viewcontroller and then seque to the second viewcontroller a second time, the UITextField will not update.

I suspect that each time i seque to the second viewcontroller, i am creating a new instance of that controller and when i try and update the UITextField i am still updating the first instance of the viewcontroller which is not visible.

It fells as though i should address the UITextField in someway like UITextFied[current viewcontroller].text = "Hello World".

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your two view controllers of your storyboard? Remember that you do not have to connect a segue from second screen to the first screen if you already have showed/presented the second screen from the first screen.

Comment: a segue will create the destination view controller as and when needed. when you use your back button the second VC will be deallocated and lose its state. notifications will fire once only, so you should receive and store the data from the notification and load it as required.If you have access to the data in the first controller, then during your segue you can pass the data to the second view controller

Comment: See: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-pass-data-between-two-view-controllers